# Cannot access elements inside shadow root

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

I have the following document structure as shown in the elements inspector:

```
<page-editor>
   #shadow-root (open)
      <div style="height: 100vh">
         <page-gallery>
            #shadow-root (open)
               <div>Title</div>
               <div class="gallery-item"></div>
               <div class="gallery-item"></div>
               <div class="gallery-item"></div>
               <div class="gallery-item"></div>
               ...
```

Inside the page-editor code, this code returns the gallery node:

```
let gallery = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('page-gallery') as HtmlElement;
console.log(gallery);
```

The console shows:

```
<page-gallery>
   #shadow-root (open)
      <div>Title</div>
      <div class="gallery-item"></div>
      <div class="gallery-item"></div>
      <div class="gallery-item"></div>
      <div class="gallery-item"></div>
      ...
```

But if I call `gallery.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.gallery-item')`, it returns empty list `NodeList []`.  I'm at a lost, please help.

Comment: You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I know already, it's because it takes time for the inner shadow root to populate itself.  I saw the node list when i tried to query inside a timeout.

Comment: Then also see the blogpost I wrote yesterday: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-developers-do-not-connect-with-the-connectedcallback-yet-4jo7